# What WebSocket server for 100,000 concurrent connections?

Tags: html, websocket

Is there any websocket server, which could serve up to 100,000 connections? I expect the implementation of websockets be built upon [RFC-6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

Answer (score 4):

Try [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). It's designed for high-performance servers. It has a web sockets implementation. See [this blog post](http://martinzoldano.blogspot.com/2010/01/websockets-netty.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Tornado webserver. Tornado has a webs ockets implementation. See http://bret.appspot.com/entry/web-sockets-in-tornado

Answer (score -2):

Yes, any server will probably handle that if you throw enough hardware at it.